# Using prod / dev files in Angular/JavaScript with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am currently using Webpack with Angular and I would like to inject/use variables depending on weather it is development or production.

I have Webpack already setup for this to detect if prod or dev but I am having a problem sending variables to JavaScript / Angular.

I thought initially the solution was using DefinePlugin but this isn't available as a global variable in JavaScript / Angular.

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    API_URL: JSON.stringify('testing')
  }),
```

Does anyone know a solution to this? I just really need to send in variables or files to angular depending weather its production or development. An example is the use of a API backend base url. It's different in development to production.

Commenting lines out seems such a bad idea if there is some way of supporting this in an automated way.

As I say, I already have a variable in Webpack to decided if its production or dev but just having an issue telling Angular / JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: `API_URL` should be available globally, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479372/use-node-env-in-source-code-to-control-build-process-with-webpack

Comment: You have to realize that `DefinePlugin` works at _compile_ time. In other words, it will replace occurrences of `API_URL` in your code to its defined value when it gets bundled. So it'll only be available for code that gets processed by Webpack.

Comment: Ah yes so it is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the DefinePlugin following the example in the [docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin). It seems to work for me. Maybe checkout updating your webpack and DefinePlugin version?

If you use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io) you can also inject environment variables using the [inline environment variables transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-inline-environment-variables/).

Comment: Yes it does work, was me. I like the babel plugin - very nice too