# Passing the NODE_ENV value using Webpack via DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to inject the `NODE_ENV` value into my code using `webpack` via `DefinePlugin`. I checked, more or less, an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479372/use-node-env-in-source-code-to-control-build-process-with-webpack/34480055?noredirect=1#comment70581497_34480055), but still can't get it to work.

Specifically, here's my setup.

In `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development && node webpack-dev-server.js"
},
```

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
"use strict";

/* requiring the modules */
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

/* defining the source and distribution paths */
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
// const PRODUCTION = !!process.argv.find((element) => element === '--production');
// const DEVELOPMENT = !!process.argv.find((element) => element === '--development');


/* defining the entries*/
const productionEntries = {
    home: SRC_DIR + "/_home.js",
    about: SRC_DIR + "/_about.js",
};
const developmentEntries = Object.assign({}, productionEntries, {webpackDevServer: ["webpack/hot/dev-server", "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080"]});
const entries = PRODUCTION ? productionEntries : developmentEntries;


/* defining the output */
const output = {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: DIST_DIR,
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    pathinfo: true,
    library: "MyLibraryName"
};


/* defining the plugins */
const plugins = PRODUCTION
    ? [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({comments: false}),
    ]
    :  [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ];

plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor.bundle", minChunks: 2}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        PRODUCTION: PRODUCTION,
        DEVELOPMENT: DEVELOPMENT,
    })
);


/* defining the modules -> rules -> loaders */
const modules = {
    rules:
        [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options:
                    {
                        presets: ["react", ["es2015", {modules: false}], "stage-2"]
                    }
            }
        ]
};



/* building the webpack config object */
const config = {
    entry: entries,
    output: output,
    module: modules,
    plugins: plugins,
    devtool: "source-map",
    target: "web",
    stats: "verbose"
};

/* exporting the webpack config */
module.exports = config;
```

And, finally, in `_about.js` I have the following:

```
// output after using: npm run dev
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // prints undefined
console.log(PRODUCTION); // prints false
console.log(DEVELOPMENT); // prints false

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

**The problem**:

- since `npm run dev` runs successfully (i.e., the server starts and the plugins and entries are adequtlly selected), I don't understand why the output for `console.log(DEVELOPMENT)` is `false`, and why `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` prints `undefined`.
- in the conditional checks performed inside the `webpack.config.js`, the `NODE_ENV` value is picked properly, otherwise the the plugins, entries, and the development server wouldn't work. However, I can't pass that value down to `_about.js` using `DefinePlugin`.
- I also tried `EnvironmentPlugin`, same result.

**My question**: Can you, please, help me *understand* where things break?

---

**Edit 1:**

I tried the following without any improvements:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION),
    DEVELOPMENT: JSON.stringify(DEVELOPMENT)
})
```

I am running `node.js` on `Windows 10`.

---

**Edit 2:**

Tried:

```
const DEVELOPMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

// with this inside plugins:
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env.PRODUCTION": JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION),
    "process.env.DEVELOPMENT": JSON.stringify(DEVELOPMENT)
})
```

and (using `npm run dev`) I get the following output:

```
console.log(process.env.PRODUCTION); // false
console.log(process.env.DEVELOPMENT); // false
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // undefined
console.log(PRODUCTION); // Uncaught ReferenceError: PRODUCTION is not defined
console.log(DEVELOPMENT); // Uncaught ReferenceError: DEVELOPMENT is not defined
```

No improvements unfortunately.

---

**Edit 3:**

My `devDependencies` are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0-rc.0"
}
```

---

**Edit 4: (solved)**

@Cleiton spotted the issue. It had to do with the how the `npm` scripts are constructed using `cross-env`. See the complete answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `cross-env` in a wrong way. It only changes env variables for its context, so when you use '&&' to run webpack it is already gone and webpack see nothing.

So you MUST write

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node webpack-dev-server.js"
},
```

note that you have wrote right for "build" script.

Another question is about that If you want do references to "process.env.PRODUCTION" inside your code base you should write:

```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env.PRODUCTION": JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION),
        "proccess.env.DEVELOPMENT": JSON.stringify(DEVELOPMENT),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Cleiton. I am trying right now. Will provide feedback in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I tried your answer and, in `_about.js`, the output for `console.log(process.env.PRODUCTION)` and `console.log(process.env.DEVELOPMENT)` is `false`. The `console.log(PRODUCTION)` or `console.log(DEVELOPMENT)` outputs `Uncaught ReferenceError: PRODUCTION is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks @Cleiton. Can't wait to check it out!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Cleiton. It works! I can't believe what the issue was. You made my day! I will mark your post as the accepted answer as soon as it allows me.

Comment: For future searches, this is from webpack's [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-environment)

Answer (score 3):

The DefinePlugin expects strings so you need to `JSON.stringify()` any values passed into it.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION),
    DEVELOPMENT: JSON.stringify(DEVELOPMENT)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Soviut. I've already tried it, but no improvements. I will edit my question to incorporate your answer.