# how to set enviroment variable value in pre-processor in webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack-2, preprocessor

I am using webpack 2 and added preprocessor in it. now I am passing NODE_ENV variable value from command line. in java script I am able to access that value but my preprocessor condition is getting failed
please anyone let me know how to set argument value in preprocessor?

here is my config file

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/app.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!preprocess-loader?+DEBUG',
        // query: {
        //   presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        //   plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        // }
      },
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"

    }, {
        test: /\.htm?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'preprocess-loader?+DEBUG',
     }

    ] 

    },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "demo.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),

  ],
};
```

my app.js

```
//@if process.env.NODE_ENV !=='production'
console.log("hi this dev")
console.log("environment",process.env.NODE_ENV)
//@endif
console.log("this is working")
```

when I saw console it is showing production as value of `process.env.NODE_ENV)` but if is getting failed I checked with exclude condition it is working fine

command I used to run is  **npm start --env.NODE_ENV='production'**
please let me know how to access variable in pre processor?

EDIT 1:
I mentioned I can get value but it is not being set in my preprocessor

EDIT 2:
Now I am getting value as undefined I added from that answer like this way

```
"dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && webpack-dev-server",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Environment variables from within package.json \[Node.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js)

Comment: @FahadNisar: I tried that way m not able to access it in if condition of preprocessor.

Comment: and in that way my console is showing value undefined

Comment: hi finally I got my answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705888/passing-the-node-env-value-using-webpack-via-defineplugin) post